# Generating elements in Django from Python list

Tags: python, django, django-templates, iteration, element

Im havin trouble generating elements from a for loop via iteration of a py list in Django.
Using Metro UI as front end framework.

```
import os
img_dir = os.listdir("static/img/sasha_banks")
#print(img_dir)
#  <img src="{% static 'img/sasha_banks/sasha_banks5.jpg' %}"> 
def sasha_files():
    sasha_dir = []
    for img in img_dir:
        sasha_dir.append(f'img/sasha_banks/{img}')  
        print(sasha_dir)

sasha_files()
```

Above python script works i jist cant seem to get to that sasha_dir list.

The commented  was the hard coded django that works, im just trying to read the directory, pushthe filepath and concat the files in dir and then iterate that list to create

```
{% for n in sasha_dir %} 
      <img src="{% static sasha_dir[n] %}"> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you revise the indentation of the shared code

Comment: Done. Sorry working from phone.

Comment: why don't you return the `sasha_dir` from the function instead of printing it to console?

Comment: All the python was just a quick draft to get the data in the format i need for the element in the <img>. The for loop is whats giving me a trouble im fairly fluent with JS dom manipulation so i just thought that would work, but   {% for n in sasha_dir %} ] doesnt seem to be iterating the sasha_dir

Answer (score 0):

**Use the inbuilt function glob**

```
#Devil
from glob import glob
from ntpath import basename
img_dir = glob("static/img/sasha_banks/*")
print(sasha_dir)

def sasha_files():
    sasha_dir = []
    for img in img_dir:
        name = basename(img)
        sasha_dir.append('img/sasha_banks/' + name)  
        print(sasha_dir)
```